# inserting data into normalized tables from de-normalized tables with the help of insert select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to take data out from denormalized table and insert it into normalized tables.

I have four normalized tables
Table1 : students (sid int)

Table2: dimensions (dim_id int, dim_name varchar(255))

Table3: homeworks( hw_id int, hw_name varchar(255))

Table4: peer_evaluation(id int, evaluator_id foreign key references students(sid), evaluated_id foreign key references students(sid), dim_id foreign key references dimensions(dim_id), hw_id foreign key references homeworks(hw_id), rating int)

And one denormalized table:

Junk (evaluator_id int, evaluated_id int, dim1 int, dim2 int, dim3 int, dim4 int, dim5 int, dim6 int, hw_name varchar(255)) and it has following data

[image: junk table]

The values in dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, dim5, dim6 are the ratings which evaluator gave to other student for respective dimensions.

I have taken data from junk table inserted the data in first 3 tables, but now I want to take out data from junk table and other 3 tables and insert into my table4.

I have tried with the following query which works but I also wants to insert dim_id(6 id's) and ratings from the junk table and insert it into peer_evaluation table in one time. can anyone help me out with this and tell me how to modify my query in order to make it work.

```
insert into peer_evaluation(evaluator_id, evaluated_id, hw_name)
select evaluator_id, evaluated_id, hw_name 
from students s, dimensions d, homeworks h, junk j 
where j.evaluator_id=s.sid and j.evaluated_id=s.sid and h.hw_name = j.hw_name;
```

Comment: Your query has some issues as it's currently written, did you copy it correctly?  Note `hw_name,)` and `j.hw_name)`.  You have an extra comma and parenthesis.

Comment: yeah I noticed it afterposting my question, I will edit it.